# Publication Mapping for SDL 8.5 and DXA 1.8

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.8

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and DXA 1.8 Java application. Also we have few publications in Web 8.5. How DXA 1.8 java application having mapping with Web 8.5 Publications.

Example: I have publications "500 Sample 1", "500 Sample 2"
I am trying to access the "500 Sample 2" Publication using my DXA 1.8 Java application using http://localhost:8080 URL. I just want understand how this localhost URL will be mapped with publication "500 Sample 2".

Answer (score 3):

In SDL Web 8 and higher, Publication - URL mapping is done using Topology Manager.

In Topology Manager you define all your Websites (e.g. `http://localhost:8080`) and Web Applications (e.g. a DXA Web App running at website root level). You also define mappings between CM Publications and those Web Applications.

To see this in practice, run those PowerShell cmdlets:

- `Get-TtmWebsite`
- `Get-TtmWebApplication`
- `Get-TtmMapping`

You can also see the information in the CME:

- Topology Manager section shows CD Environments, Websites and Web Applications
- Publishing tab in Publication properties shows Mappings

Comment: Thanks Rick. We have CMS in one server and our DXA web App in another Server. Can I still use http://localhost:8080 url to map my publication. Also can we map multiple URL to same publication(e.g http://localhost:8080 for running in local machine; http://someQAenvironmentURL.com for accessing it through public domain)

Comment: In general, you do not (only) want to use `localhost` URLs for your websites, because that will make them accessible only on the server where the site is hosted. And, yes, you can specify multiple Base URLs for a Website in Topology Manager.  Note that if you specify multiple Base URLs, the first one has a special meaning for the system: it becomes the *Primary Base URL*. This is the URL that, for example, the "View On Site" feature in the CME will use.